# Is there a website or free downloadable program to identify and remove malware from an ISO file?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware

Is there a website or free downloadable program that allows a user to identify and remove multiple types of malware from an ISO file?

Comment: Can malware infest an image file?  I mean, beside naming an executable on Windows NudeJenniferLopez.jpg.exe and praying someoe is dumb enough to click it, does any image file format have enough executable or interperable parts to carry malware?

Comment: The image could exploit a vulnerability in a popular image viewer or codec, like the old [ANI vulnerability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/935423) in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> it could issue updates through fully functioning bitmap

So you're talking about stripping out steganography rather than neutralizing malware - in which case you'd get some mileage out of converting the file format (then possibly converting it back again). However it is technically possible to embed the content in such a way that it is still recoverable (IIRC the [hidden WoW user id](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-general/375573-looking-inside-your-screenshots.html) is extractable from a photo of the screen in addition to a direct image grab) e.g. if the image is of a barcode, then converting the format is not likely to disrupt the value embedded in the bar code.